# Hosting WCF service with HTTPS

Tags: wcf, header, https, host

I am hosting a WCF service using HTTPS, and I am running into a problem with the address being set to the netbios name of the machine I am running it on. This is easily remedied if I just want to use HTTP by adding a host header, but unfortunately, you cannot add host headers to HTTPS bindings. (you can on the command line, but my IT department isn't crazy about hacks like that).

I've searched pretty much everywhere I can think of. I'm wondering if anyone else has this problem, or if they all just expose their APIs over HTTP? Thanks.

If more information is necessary, I'd be happy to provide it.

Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to post images to show the issue. The metadata page is telling me to use https://mcweb1-prod.powertochange.local/TMC_API.svc?wsdl, but I'd like it to use an external address instead.

Comment: Are you hosting the WCF service with IIS?

Comment: yes. I've tried with IIS6 on Win 2k3 and IIS7 on Win 2k8, neither seems to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the HTTPS binding in IIS unfortunately it does not let you manually set or read the URL from the cert.  This [link](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html) explains how to properly change the address in the metadata.

Comment: Matt, that worked great, thanks. A little bit of followup information for anyone else having the same problem, the secret sauce was using a wildcard SSL cert. Made it possible to set the host headers properly without hacking on the command line. (I believe this is only available in IIS7)